# How to handle two database insertions fom a single form in spring/ hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, mapping

I have 3 model classes,

```
User.java

public class UserData {
private Integer userID;
private String userName;
private String userPassword;
//getters and setters..
```

and Permission class like..

```
Permission.java

public class PermissionsData {
private Integer permissionID;
private Integer userID;
private Integer moduleID;
private boolean permissionIsReadOnly;
private boolean permissionIsModify;
private boolean permissionIsFull;
//getters and setters
```

amd module class like,

```
module.java

public class ModuleData {
private Integer modId;
private String modName;
```

I have some modules in my database. When i am creating a new user, i had listed those modules and had added checkboxes to set permissions. When submitting the form, i need to insert user data to user table and his permissions for each module to the Permission table.

Now i had implemented only inserting roles to the database.. my controller is like..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addRole")
    public ModelAndView addNewRole()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("addNewRole");
        RoleData role = new RoleData();
        mav.getModelMap().put("roleDataObj", role);

        List<ModuleData> moduleList = moduleService.getAllModules();
        mav.getModelMap().addAttribute("ModuleList", moduleList);
        return mav;
    }
```

How can i achieve to add data to two tables on one submit?? i would also like to know about the mapping betwewen modules and permission
I am really new to this spring and hibernate. So plz guide me with sample codes..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://javainnovations.blogspot.in/2008/07/batch-insertion-in-hibernate.html this link will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

if you have set cascading in the mapping

```
@Cascade(Cascade.all)
private List<Permission> permissions;
```

it is as simple as

```
public void saveNewUser(...)
{
    User user = new User();
    // fill properties
    Permission p = new Permission();
    // fill properties
    user.getPermissions().add(p);

    session.save(user);
}
```

Update: the code above would be possible using a class structure like. the important part is the collection/map of permissions each user has per modul

```
public class Permission {
    private boolean IsReadOnly;
    private boolean IsModify;
    private boolean IsFull;
}

public class Module {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}

public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private Map<Module, Permission> permissions;
}
```

and mapping

```
<class name="User">
  ...
  <map name="permissions" cascade="all">
    <key column="UserId"/>
    <index-many-to-many column="ModuleId" class="Module"/>
    <composite-element class="Permission">
      <property name="IsReadOnly"/>
      <property name="IsModify"/>
      <property name="IsFull"/>
    </composite-element>
  </map>
```

Comment: It made me a it confused.. Then where do i implement the cascade? Can u put down ur idea with a description? so that it will be helpful to others also..

Comment: the cascading is set in the mapping. i posted the mapping with xml but there is an equivalent with annotations

Comment: i had tried it dear.. but not yet successful. May be some logical problems. Can u help me with some codes. Or can u plz suggest me some examples.. And i want to use annotations..